# Automatically choose Microsoft account based on Edge profile when signing in

Tags: microsoft-edge, azure

I have two emails for work:

- first.last@org.ca
- admin.first.last@org.ca

I have an edge profile signed in to each of the accounts.
I often use the Azure portal with the admin account, but when I open Azure portal things in new tabs it always shows the Microsoft "choose your account" thing.

Since the admin profile detects the normal account since it's what I sign in to Windows with, the admin profile always thinks there's two Microsoft accounts to choose from.

How can I force the admin edge profile to always sign in with the admin account?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, there's a setting for this.

After enabling "Automatically sign in to sites with your current work or school account?", it no longer shows the "choose your account" sign in page when duplicating or opening Azure portal tabs :D

[image]

[image]